# How to show unread notification counter on Tabs inside TabLayout?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabs, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I am using [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) of android support design library.

I want to show unread notification counter on the tab with title like below image.

[image]

How to set unread count on `Tab` inside `TabLayout`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `public TabLayout.Tab setCustomView (int layoutResId)`

Create a `Layout` with `TextView` and `Button` use this in Custom view.

For reference

[setCustomView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(int))

[Example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-custom-view-to-tablayout)

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: This is partially working for me, when I try to change the counter/badge in runtime, I call the setCustomView again, and it's adding the same view instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [android-viewbadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)...