# How to show Notification Counter in a Tablayout?

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, badge

I saw [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269517/how-to-show-unread-notification-counter-on-tabs-inside-tablayout) but it didn't help me understand what I had to do. I understand the concept of how I am going to increment the counter's value from my query.

But I don't understand what I should use. Should I use `Notification notification;` or `BadgeViewer badgeViewer;`? I would prefer a way where I don't have to import a library.

Comment: The accepted answer of the post suggests setting a custom layout for the tabs instead of using the default layout. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: My app consists of 5 tabs. The 4th tab is a fragment which contains a list view to show notifications. When the user opens the app, I want to show a red counter by the tab icon to show the number of unread notifications but am unsure of how to do this. @Karakuri

Comment: You can create your own layout and set that as the view for the tab, so it will show your layout instead of the normal text. You can also use [`getTabAt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#getTabAt(int)) and [`getCustomView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#getCustomView()) to get the views for that tab and make modifications.

Comment: Could you provide code and give me an answer? @Karakuri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a layout resource for your tabs. It should include something that represents your "badge" (a simple `TextView` will work if you just want to show a number). When you create the tabs, specify this custom layout.

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;

// in onCreate()
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TABS; i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab()
            .setText("tab name")
            .setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab);
}
```

Note that for `setText()` to work properly, your layout needs a `TextView` with `android:id="@android:id/text1"` (this is not the badge text, this is the tab name).

When you want to update the badge for a tab, you can get the `Tab` and ask for its view, find the badge, and set its text.

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(3); // fourth tab
View tabView = tab.getCustomView();
TextView badgeText = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.badge_text);
badgeText.setText(...);
```

Comment: I will try this soon and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Why not also include a sample XML file?

Answer (score 5):

user material design instead of apcompact design and here is the one line code to add badge to tab like whatsapp

```
  tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getOrCreateBadge().setNumber(3);//tab#1
```

so this will add badge to the tab you wanted

> to remove the badge on tab selected

```
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(
                        int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

              

                    if (position == 0) {
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).removeBadge();
                    }
                    if (position == 2) {
                   

                        
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(2 ).removeBadge();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            });
```