# How to add badges in Tablayout in Android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

In my application I want use `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` for set some fragments.
But I want show number (counter of data) next to the text such as badges .

I searched on google but not find good way!

Can you tell me which library to use or say me good way for my request?

thanks a lot

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32889885/5594218) Hope this will help you

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968162/android-tablayout-tabs-with-notification-badge-like-whatsapp

Comment: Or this. https://gist.github.com/eneim/55df01e092520a6d33a4 . You have not searched Google....

Comment: I would suggest you for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493102/6383029

Comment: @aksacha, I want use this library : https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout  . are support badges?

Comment: @Michal_196,  I want use this library : https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout  . are support badges?

Comment: you have to pass only target view in the [Android ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/README.markdown) library

Comment: @aksacha, thanks my friend, but I am amateur and I should create this :( :( can you send me full code? please

Comment: @Us_pk have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @aksacha, can you send me your skype id? I write codes and show to ue for help me. please

Comment: You could use this library: https://github.com/egemenmede/etiyabadgetab?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5418

Comment: @Michal_196, thanks my friend

Comment: check my answer hope it will solve your issue [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66254957/14588625](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66254957/14588625)